# First if statement in an always block always evaluated to true initially

Tags: verilog

I am trying to write an always block that displays its corresponding number on the segment display of the FPGA.For some reason the first if conditional is evaluated to true initially even though the switch is turned off :

```
always @(posedge i2 or posedge i1)
begin
 if(i2)
    inp11 = x5;
  else
    if(i1)
        inp11 = x9;

end
```

inp11 is intially set to 0, so i am expecting that when i first turn on the FPGA, inp11 would dispay a 0.However a 5 is displayed (value of x5) and then i can switch between 5 and 9 normally and correctly.So how is it possible that inp11 is set to 5 with the switch i2 not being turned on?

Comment: What does you simulation show?

Comment: I didn't run a simulation,I put the output on the board.

Comment: You can afford not to simulate if you have a few years HDL experience, which I could see from your code you do not have. To answer HDL questions we require the code and the test bench . Simulate first, look at the waveform and start debugging. Also have a look around the internet how Verilog code looks like. Start using a clock and do ***not*** treat Verilog/VHDL like the other 'standard' programming languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the log file, it probably is reporting warnings with your code. What you inferred is an very ugly level-sensitive latch. There will be a behaviorally mismatch between RTL simulation and post synthesis.

If you intend combinational logic:

```
always @*
begin
  if(i2)
    inp11 = x5;
  else if(i1)
    inp11 = x9;
  else
    inp11 = 'h0; // or some other deterministic value. Do NOT use inp11=inpt11
    // Without the final 'else', a level-sensitive latch is inferred
end
```

If you intend synchronous logic:

```
always @(posedge clk)
begin
  if(i2)
    inp11 <= x5;
  else if(i1)
    inp11 <= x9;
end
```

Comment: Thank you this worked ! I am working on uni project that requires me to create a small math game where there are 3 levels each level is associated with 1 equation of single digits and there is a counter to answer those equations.So far i have converted the equations to appear on the 7 segment display.If you don't mind,can you give me an overview on how to do this assignment?

Comment: I should add that my current problem is verifying the answers,As in I have stored answers and the input changes correctly now but i can't verify the answers.